# Populating the data and should be disabled

Tags: jsp

In our application having two boxes , in one box data is populating using `html:optionsCollection` tag and i want to get only one element from the first box and should be populated in the second box and it should be disables.

```
<html:select multiple="true" property="buildingOptions">
    <html:optionsCollection property="buildingFieldsList" />
</html:select>
```

Comment: Not getting your problem..

Comment: Is this jsp or javascript?